# An application of Fermat's little theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given that $p$ be a prime and $a$ and $b$ are integers not divisible by $p$, prove that 
$$(a+b)^{p} \equiv( a^p + b ^p ) \pmod{p}$$

**My approach** : By Fermat's little theorem,
$$a^p \equiv a \pmod{p}$$
and 
$$b^p \equiv b \pmod{p}$$
Then 
$$a^p + b^p \equiv (a + b) \pmod{p}$$
Either $p \mid (a+b)$ or $p \nmid (a+b) $. In the former, 
$$(a+b)^p \equiv 0 \equiv (a+b) \pmod{p}$$
In the latter, 
$$(a+b)^p \equiv (a+b) \pmod{p}$$
follows from F.L.T.

**1.** Is this approach correct ?

**2.** How to prove the result starting with the binomial theorem:
$$(a+b)^p = a^p + \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} a^{k} b^{p-k} {p \choose k} + b^p \equiv (a+b) + \bigg\{ \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} a^{k} b^{p-k} {p \choose k} \bigg\} \pmod{p}$$
How do we show that the term within the curly braces is $0 \pmod{p}$?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Freshman's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream).

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is right. To solve it using binomial theorem, note that for any $0<n<p$ we have:
$${p \choose n} =\frac{p!}{n! (p-n)! }$$
Since $n, p-n<p$, the numerator has a factor of $p$ while the denominator doesn't. This means that the whole expression in the curly brackets in your question is divisible by $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach is right, but you do not need to consider the case $a+b$ divisible by $p$: the equation $a^p\equiv a\pmod p$ holds for all integer $a$.

---

To show that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}a^kb^{p-k}\binom pk=0,
$$
it suffices to show that $\binom pk=0,\,\forall k=1,\ldots,p-1$.

Write $\binom pk=\frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}=\frac{p\cdot(p-1)\cdots(p-k+1)}{k!}$.

Now $p$ divides the numerator but does not divide the denominator of the fraction, so $p\mid\binom pk$.

---

Hope this helps.